# How to make a loop that replaces pandas dataframe elements by position

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `test` that I would like to alter the elements of. Specifically, I want to change the values in the `scale` column of the dataframe, iterating over each row except for the one with the largest `mPower`value. I want the scale values to become the value of the largest `mPower` value divided by the current row's `mPower` value. Below is a small example dataframe:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'psnum':[0,1],'scale':[1,1],'mPower':[4.89842,5.67239]})
```

My code looks like this:

```
for index, row in test.iterrows():
    if(test['psnum'][row] != bigps):
        s = morepower/test['mPower'][row]
        test.at[:,'scale'][row] = round(s,2)
```

where `bigps = 1` (ie. the value of the `psnum` column with the largest `mPower` value) and `morepower = 5.67239` (ie. the largest value in the `mPower` column of the `test` dataframe).

When I run this code, I get the error: "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." I've tried a few different methods on this now, most of which ending in errors or nothing being changed in the dataframe at all.

So in the end, I need the `test` dataframe to be as such:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'psnum':[0,1],'scale':[1.16,1],'mPower':[4.89842,5.67239]})
```

Any insight on this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can and should avoid the loop altogether for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the sort of vectorized operation pandas is so great for. Rather than looping at all, you can use a mathematical operation and broadcast it to the whole column at once.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'psnum':[0,1],'scale':[1,1],'mPower':[4.89842,5.67239]})
test
    psnum   scale   mPower
0   0       1       4.89842
1   1       1       5.67239

test['scale']=test['scale']*(test['mPower'].max()/test['mPower']).round(2)
test
    psnum   scale   mPower
0   0       1.16    4.89842
1   1       1.00    5.67239
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm much more acquainted with R, where something like my loop would have worked just fine, but this is great. It's even nice and slick looking compared to the bulky loop I had.

Comment: Glad I could help. Just to clarify, there absolutely is a looped solution that would work fine in python as well. However, due to the numpy underlying pandas dataframes, looping is much slower and more resource intensive, and is really a last-resort option when there's no vectorizable mathematical ops being done.

Answer (score 0):

please try this :

```
for index, row in test.iterrows():
    if(test.iloc[index]['psnum'] != bigps):
        s = morepower/test.iloc[index]['mPower']
        test.at[index,'scale'] = round(s,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use loop. Use vetorized operation. In this case, I use series `where`

```
test['scale'] = test['scale'].where(test.mPower == test.mPower.max(), test.mPower.max()/test.mPower)

Out[652]:
    mPower  psnum     scale
0  4.89842      0  1.158004
1  5.67239      1  1.000000
```